# serializeArray function not returning input field values and tinyMCE text area value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#form1').submit(function(){
     var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
     form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
     alert(form_data);
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



 <form id="form1" onSubmit="return false;" method="post" name="form1" action="">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" name="fname" value="" placeholder="First Name" class="resume_builder_input">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" name="lname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="resume_builder_input">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
          <textarea class="text_area_class summary_text_editor" name="summary_box" rows="4" cols="50">  
          </textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am collecting form data with `serializeArray` function but it is not returning all input field values on first click. It works on second click of form submit button but on first click it returns empty values for most of the input fields.
Here is my complete function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#form1').submit(function(){
     var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
     form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
     alert(form_data);
   })
})
```

Here is few input fields from my form

```
 <form id="form1" onSubmit="return false;" method="post" name="form1" action="">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" name="fname" value="" placeholder="First Name" class="resume_builder_input">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" name="lname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="resume_builder_input">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
          <textarea class="text_area_class summary_text_editor" name="summary_box" rows="4" cols="50">  
          </textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to mention that I have assigned name attribute to all input fields. Any idea why it is happening and how I can fix this.

Comment: you need to post a complete example.  Seriously, look at what you posted and ask how is someone going to be able to answer with this information.  The more effort you put into your questions, like supplying a snippet the faster and more complete answer you will get

Comment: @DCR I have added more code now in my question. But again I want to mention that on first click few input field values are missing but on second click it return all input fields

Comment: The code you have provided works: http://jsfiddle.net/9bLn8ydw/. Please provide an [MCVE] that actually replicates the problem.

Comment: Yes it is working in Jsfiddle but on my website is not returning any thing.on first click. Also it is happening only with few input fields

Comment: It is nearly impossible for us to help you if we can not replicate the issue. Please post code that replicates the issue. Does that exact code produce the same issue on your site, including those and only those inputs? Are there any console errors. Try using `console.log()` instead of alert to double check.

Comment: There is no console errors, Should I Share my website URL with you ?

Comment: Ideally you should reduce the problem to the smallest possible amount of code to replicate the issue, then share that with us. This is an important tool in debugging. It may even help you to solve the problem yourself. We generally try and avoid links to "problem sites" as they are a moving target and once fixed are useless to those who come looking for help with a similar problem. If you add your site as a comment I will have a **very** quick look. Also clarify if that exact code with those inputs has the problem.

Comment: Are you able to figure out this issue ?

Comment: OK Now I'm irritated! At no point have you mentioned that you are using rich text editors. These are NOT standard form elements and have a whole heap of extra JavaScript associated with them which more than likely is interfering here. Try recreating you page with standard fields and test your script. If it works then, you know it's some thing to do with the editors.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your time and help. I did not mention this because it is not only happening with rich text editor fields.

Comment: My advice....tear it down to the minimum, the form and the submit function. Add the remaining functionality one component at a time, testing each time. When it breaks, now you have narrowed the problem down and try and work out how that component is interfearing.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your suggestion. I am already trying to figure out this in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added these two lines before implementing `serializeArray` function and now it is working for me.

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
jQuery(".resume_builder_input").trigger("change");
```

Comment: this doesn't make any sense. tinyMCE  is undefined

Comment: It is a library for advance text editor. I have this library included in my website and triggerSave() is a function which help me to fix this issue. Now I am able to submit complete form data on first click successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing us the complete code. Below is a working solution. It might help, how you have placed your submit button. Look at the solution below and run it to see if it works as desired.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#form1').submit(function() {
    var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
    form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
    alert(form_data);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" onSubmit="return false;" method="post" name="form1" action="">
  <div class="col-sm-6"> <input type="text" name="fname" value="" placeholder="First Name" class="resume_builder_input"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"> <input type="text" name="lname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="resume_builder_input"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12"> <textarea class="text_area_class summary_text_editor" name="summary_box" rows="4" cols="50">             </textarea> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </div>
</form>

<hr>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Please let me know if it helps.